# How to use rsync selecting no file

Tags: rsync

I would like to use the `--delete` capability of `rsync` to erase everyting on a destination directory.

What I am currently doing is:

```
rsync -zavr --delete ./input_dir_1/ user@host:dest_dir/
rsync -zavr ./input_dir_2/ user@host:dest_dir/
rsync -zavr ./input_dir_3/ user@host:dest_dir/
```

But in order to use `rsync` in a loop, is there a way to first select no input file (and use `--delete` to just delete everything)? Ideally I would like something like:

```
# Delete everything on destination dir
rsync -zavr --delete /dev/null user@host:dest_dir/

# Now iterate over all input directories (could use a for loop)
rsync -zavr ./input_dir_1/ user@host:dest_dir/
rsync -zavr ./input_dir_2/ user@host:dest_dir/
rsync -zavr ./input_dir_3/ user@host:dest_dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

1. rsync uses ssh. Why not delete directly? (Be careful not to delete the wrong directory!)

```
ssh user@host 'rm -rf dest_dir; mkdir dest_dir'
```

2. You can use the exclude feature of rsync:

```
rsync -r --exclude='*' --delete-excluded / user@host:dest_dir/
```

Any folder will work for the source.